# Concat() in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

im having a problem  concatenating string in a mysql query.

here is my query:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) AS fullname FROM user WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR apellido LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR email LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR about LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR place LIKE '%$busqueda%' or fullname LIKE '%$busqueda%'
```

however the query fails: 
`Query failed: Unknown column 'fullname' in 'where clause'`

Proabably is just a sintax mistake, thx

Comment: A lots of answers. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference aliases in the WHERE clause.

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.
>
> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed. See [Section C.5.5.4, “Problems with Column Aliases”.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html)

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

You can change:

```
... OR fullname LIKE '%$busqueda%'
```

to

```
... or CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) LIKE '%$busqueda%'
```

By the way, all those LIKEs are going to make your query very slow. You might want to look into a [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a comparison on a field that you create in the SELECT statement.

Use

```
or CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) LIKE %$busqueda%'
```

be aware though that this is probably impossible to optimize for the engine, so search is likely to be *very* slow. If this is for larger amounts of data, I would consider keeping a separate concatenated column for searching instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the Concat() in the WHERE also:

```
...place LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) LIKE '%$busqueda%'
```

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) AS fullname FROM user WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR apellido LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR email LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR about LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR place LIKE '%$busqueda%' or CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) LIKE '%$busqueda%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been brought out you cannot use column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This is because the `WHERE` clause is used before any values are even found, therefore the expressions in the column aliases aren't calculated until after the row(s) are retrieved.

Now, if you don't want to have to perform the CONCAT twice (one in the `SELECT`, one in the `WHERE`), you can take advantage of the `HAVING` clause. The `HAVING` clause works just like `WHERE`, only it is used *after* the rows are retrieved.

Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

`SELECT *, CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) AS fullname FROM user WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR apellido LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR email LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR about LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR place LIKE '%$busqueda%' HAVING fullname LIKE '%$busqueda%'`

Note that this may not necessarily work as well if you're looking for the best *performance*.

Comment: Yes, except that since neither nombre or apellido match by themselves, the row that might match fullname will be excluded by the WHERE clause, and hence never make it to the having clause.  You'd need to change the entire thing to Having (not have a WHERE).  But that'd be really inefficient...

Answer (score 0):

the sintax is killing me....

the next query is having problems too:

```
$cadbusca="SELECT * , MATCH (nombre, apellido, email, about, place, CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido)) AGAINST ('$busqueda') AS Score FROM user WHERE MATCH (nombre, apellido, email, about, place, CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido)) AGAINST ('$busqueda') ORDER BY Score DESC";
```

error:

```
Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(nombre,' ',apellido)) AGAINST ('dan stern') AS Score FROM user WHERE MATCH (nom' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate Your own string one parameter is string and second is column name where you want to concatenate using this code of CONCAT function

SELECT concat( 'ConcatString', `columnName` ) AS newColumnName FROM `products` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0 , 30